# How to add an icon to the font used by materialize.css?

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I'm using this framework : https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize.

I see a lot of icons but I don't find anything for the € symbol. Although there is this one $.

I'm wondering how to add a new icon, cause it is a font and I have no idea how to do it. May be it's impossible and I have to use another font instead...

Thanks for your help, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use http://fontawesome.io/icons/ which has a euro sign.

```
<i class="fa fa-eur"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to add € symbol before/after some price, use pseudo-class, just copy this symbol as it is and paste into content property:

```
:after {
  content: "€";
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Pretty straightforward, but works=)

Comment: Hah, previously tested this method =)